# Android Oreo's downloadable fonts exceptions

Tags: android, fonts

Just uploaded a new version of my app to beta with the new [Downloadable Fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html) and [Fonts in XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html) features and the pre-launch report from google is showing me crashes on some devices.

LG G6, Android 7.0:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
>   Process: com.example.mobile, PID: 11263
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke a virtual method on a null object reference
>       at android.support.v4.graphics.TypefaceCompatUtil.mmap(TypefaceCompatUtil.java:98)
>       at android.support.v4.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi24Impl.createFromFontInfo(TypefaceCompatApi24Impl.java:140)
>       at android.support.v4.graphics.TypefaceCompat.createFromFontInfo(TypefaceCompat.java:167)
>       at android.support.v4.provider.FontsContractCompat.getFontInternal(FontsContractCompat.java:190)
>       at android.support.v4.provider.FontsContractCompat.getFontSync(FontsContractCompat.java:244)
>       at android.support.v4.graphics.TypefaceCompat.createFromResourcesFamilyXml(TypefaceCompat.java:124)
>       at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:390)
>       at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:336)
>       at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:205)
>       at com.example.libs.fragments.BaseFragment.onStart(BaseFragment.java:148)
>       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2287)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1458)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
>       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2239)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.loopAndInterrogate(Interrogator.java:148)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:466)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:420)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:234)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:140)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:123)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:170)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.access$100(Tap.java:31)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:46)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:136)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:355)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:242)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:62)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:149)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:146)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)

Moto G4 Play, Android 6.0:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.mobile, PID: 13208
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.support.v4.provider.FontsContractCompat$TypefaceResult.mResult' on a null object reference
>       at android.support.v4.provider.FontsContractCompat$2.onReply(FontsContractCompat.java:277)
>       at android.support.v4.provider.FontsContractCompat$2.onReply(FontsContractCompat.java:274)
>       at android.support.v4.provider.FontsContractCompat$3.onReply(FontsContractCompat.java:312)
>       at android.support.v4.provider.FontsContractCompat$3.onReply(FontsContractCompat.java:300)
>       at android.support.v4.provider.SelfDestructiveThread$2$1.run(SelfDestructiveThread.java:149)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

P8 Lite, Android 5.0:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.mobile, PID: 19646
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #145: Error inflating class 
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:825)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:523)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:425)
>       at com.example.libs.fragments.BasicBaseFragment.initView(BasicBaseFragment.java:46)
>       at com.example.libs.fragments.BasicBaseFragment.onCreateView(BasicBaseFragment.java:73)
>       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2261)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
>       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2239)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>       ... 27 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.getFd()' on a null object reference
>       at android.support.v4.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi21Impl.getFile(TypefaceCompatApi21Impl.java:50)
>       at android.support.v4.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi21Impl.createFromFontInfo(TypefaceCompatApi21Impl.java:72)
>       at android.support.v4.graphics.TypefaceCompat.createFromFontInfo(TypefaceCompat.java:167)
>       at android.support.v4.provider.FontsContractCompat.getFontInternal(FontsContractCompat.java:190)
>       at android.support.v4.provider.FontsContractCompat.getFontSync(FontsContractCompat.java:244)
>       at android.support.v4.graphics.TypefaceCompat.createFromResourcesFamilyXml(TypefaceCompat.java:124)
>       at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:390)
>       at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:336)
>       at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:205)
>       at com.example.libs.widget.view.MandatoryEditTextView.initialize(MandatoryEditTextView.java:179)
>       at com.example.libs.widget.view.MandatoryEditTextView.init(MandatoryEditTextView.java:120)
>       at com.example.libs.widget.view.MandatoryEditTextView.(MandatoryEditTextView.java:98)
>       ... 30 more

I noticed in the report videos that those crashes are occurring in the first screens of the app but when i run the app myself on an emulator or a real device (Oreo or pre Oreo) this crashes dont happen.

Also, as a side note, but i think its related, i've been trying to use

```
<meta-data android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml but it doesnt seem to work at all. when trying to access a font, either via xml or by code, the app crashes because the font isnt being recognized. So i decided eventually to remove this meta-data.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you getting the fonts - via support library download or via Google Play Services?

Comment: @MorrisonChang I'm using the support library since I'm supporting api 16+ and the fonts provider is Google play services.

Comment: Did you check in app that `device must have Google Play services version 11 or higher to use the Google Fonts provider`? Version 11 was released June 2017: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_2017_-_version_110

Comment: @MorrisonChang crap! didnt do that. so actually there's no immediate gain with this new feature. unless i force the user to update google play services on app start (which is not ideal to say the least) i cannot use downloadable fonts.

Comment: For the bug for "Moto G4 Play, Android 6.0:" there is a issue filled already https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69085400

Comment: @AsafK If the majority of users keep Play Services up to date, it may not matter about the ones who don't. Also do keep in mind that you should have a fallback option for your fonts (unless its really matters). Additionally as this is a new feature, you may be discovering bugs.

Comment: this is the bug of 27.0.x appcompact support library. Not fixed yet in 27.0.2

Comment: @AsafK, I'm observing the same issue. Does it appear if a newer version of the Support library is used?